# Simple html dom pegar link "text/javascript"?

Tags: php

Como a url dentro de:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var src = "https:www.site.com";
</script>
```

Já tentei pesquisar mas os exemplos que encontro não consigo alterar para o que necessito.

O código esta assim:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$page = 'www.site.com';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($page);

$links = array(); 
foreach($html->find(script) as $element) {
   $links[] = $element;
echo $element;
}

reset($links);
```

O que eu quero é pegar o link dentro do do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var src = "https:www.site.com";
</script>
```

Retornando apenas isto: `https:www.site.com`

Comment: Explique melhor o que você esta tentando fazer.

Comment: Explique com mais detalhes, para nós entender o seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a API nativa do PHP chamada `DOMDocument` combinada com `curl` ou `file_get_contents` e depois usar `preg_match`, um exemplo simples para entender:

```
<?php
$meuhtml = '
<script type="text/javascript">
    var src = "https:www.site.com";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var    src    = \'https:www.site2.com\';
</script>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($meuhtml);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

$urls = array();

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (preg_match('#var\s+src(\s+|)=(\s+|)(".*";|\'.*\';)#', $tag->nodeValue, $match)) {
        $result = preg_replace('#^["\']|["\'];$#', '', $match[3]);
        $urls[] = $result; //Adiciona ao array
    }
}

//Mostra todas urls
print_r($urls);
```

A [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) usada `#var\s+src(\s+|)=(\s+|)(".*";|\'.*\';)#` é quem extrai os dados retornados pelo `$tag->nodeValue`. Veja funcionando em https://repl.it/Hwt4 (clica no botão <kbd>Run</kbd> quando a página carregar).

Claro que isto era um exemplo para entender o código, para baixar os dados de outro site pode-se usar o `curl` ou se no teu `php.ini` o `allow_url_fopen` for `on`, exemplo com curl:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://site.com';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$data) {
     die('Erro');
}


$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpcode !== 200) {
    die('Erro na requisição');
}

curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($data);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

$urls = array();

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (preg_match('#var\s+src(\s+|)=(\s+|)(".*";|\'.*\';)#', $tag->nodeValue, $match)) {
        $result = preg_replace('#^["\']|["\'];$#', '', $match[3]);
        $urls[] = $result; //Adiciona ao array
    }
}

//Mostra todas urls
print_r($urls);
```

Ou se quiser apenas pegar a primeira URL mude para:

```
$url = '';

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (preg_match('#var\s+src(\s+|)=(\s+|)(".*";|\'.*\';)#', $tag->nodeValue, $match)) {
        $result = preg_replace('#^["\']|["\'];$#', '', $match[3]);
        $url = $result;

        break;// Finaliza o foreach assim que encontrar a url
    }
}

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar o [XPath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) do PHP, basicamente o seguinte:

```
$html = "seu HTML obtido por file_get_content ou por cURL...";

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$XPath = new DomXPath($DOM);

$TagScriptJavascript = $XPath->query('//script[@type="text/javascript"]');

foreach($TagScriptJavascript as $item){

    if(preg_match('/var src = "(.*)";/', $item->nodeValue, $url)){

        echo $url[1];

    }

}
```

Explicações:

1. Primeiro inicia o DOM com o seu HTML, obtido de qualquer forma.
2. O `$TagScriptJavascript` retornará todos os elementos que forem `script` e que possuírem o atributo de `type` com o valor de `text/javascript`, conforma a query (`//script[@type="text/javascript"]`).
3. O `foreach` irá fazer a opção `4` por cada `$TagScriptJavascript` obtido.
4. O `preg_match` irá buscar por `var src="(qualquer coisa)";`, se ele achar irá mostrar, devido ao `echo $url[1]`.

---

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c0d8d0c14697a6adf725a4cd2b6b639b8d33af4)

Comment: `type=text/javascript`? Tem gente que usa e tem gente que não :), pessoalmente acho o uso de `DomXPath` neste caso especifico desnecessário, para outros casos ele é uma ótima opção e realmente facilita a vida.

Comment: Utilizei mais pelo titulo, `pegar link “text/javascript”`, fiquei com isto na cabeça, não que realmente seja necessário. O maior problema acho que seja o REGEX, que está simplório, qualquer espaço a mais ele quebra, o que sua resposta "prevê" isto.